# Multiple flash ads changing the way they are stacked....only in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome

I have three flash files that are all stacked on top of each other. There is a background, a foreground, and a close button. When in Chrome, they will sometimes change which one has a higher z-index (although this is not confirmed the inspector). They stay as expected in FF and Safari though.

Here is the code:

```
$('<div id="overlay_wrapper" />').appendTo('body').append('<div id="overlay_background" />').append('<div id="overlay_foreground" />').append('<div id="overlay_button"/>');
var flashvars = {}; 
var params = {}; 
params.allowscriptaccess = 'always'; 
var attributes = {};
params.wmode = "transparent";
params.scale = "exactfit"; // try setting this as default if noborder doesnt work
var flashvars = {}; 
var params = {}; 
params.allowscriptaccess = 'always';
var attributes = {};

var win_width = $(window).width();
var win_height = $(window).height();
var dim = {
    'width' : win_width,
    'height' : win_height
};
$('#overlay_wrapper').css(dim);

swfobject.embedSWF(custom_takeover_options.wallpaper_url, 'overlay_background', win_width, win_height, '9.0.0',"expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes, function(){
    swfobject.embedSWF(custom_takeover_options.foreground_url, 'overlay_foreground', custom_takeover_options.foreground_width, custom_takeover_options.foreground_height, '9.0.0',"expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes, function(){
            swfobject.embedSWF(custom_takeover_options.close_url, 'overlay_button', 150, 40, '9.0.0',"expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    });
});
```

Any thoughts would help!

Thanks

Comment: updated! I'm using swfobject.

Comment: Try hard coding the divs in the body instead of Jquery. I think your issues are with jQuery. Also wmode = "transparent" has been known to not be reliable